# Python way to stop pc from going to sleep/lock

Tags: python, windows

I'm working in a firm where all the PCs are managed by AD. I just don't like my PC going to sleep and getting locked afterwards for a specific time is passed(which I believe is quite small). I tried to make a small python program to keep the mouse moving at certain instances using Pyautogui and ctypes but neither of them seemed to work for me. Is there a fool-proof way to do this? I cannot change the time the PC sleeps as these settings are disabled and are managed by AD admins.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/196/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that on a **windows computer**:

Warning ! this code is somehow "invasive" because it will make your mouse pointer clicking.

```
import win32api, win32con
import time

x = 0
y = 0
timer = 60

def click(x,y):
  win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

while True:
  click(x, y)
  time.sleep(timer)
```

This code simply gonna make your mouse pointer clicking at the (0, 0) screen coordinates each minutes

Comment: Simulating mouse clicks surely is the most invasive way to accomplish this task...

Comment: That was an exemple, it's of course invasive but expecting the computer not going in sleep mode mean that you are not using it ... you also can just move the mouse pointer without clicking. As i said that only was an exemple of what the library win32api allow you to do

Comment: A poor example at that. More so, since the system already allows you to [do just that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) without interfering with the users' input devices.

Comment: If you read carefully what Dev Tomar K asked, you can see that he talked about trying to keep the mouse moving ... but he didn't manage to get it works. It seems that "invasive" way to make it works isn't a problem for him, that's why i gave an exemple, probably a poor exemple as you said but which would satisfy the one who asked for it.

Comment: Since you apparently forgot to take the [tour], make sure to do it now. You'll learn that Stack Overflow isn't about *"the one who asked"* **at all**.

Comment: I already took the tour. I agree Stack Overflow isn't about "the one who asked" but i continue thinking that the **MAIN** objective still is to answer to the question asked when it's possible.

Comment: You took the tour, 10 minutes ago. For the first time. The **MAIN** objective of Stack Overflow is to provide **quality** solutions. This isn't, and I [outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707068/python-way-to-stop-pc-from-going-to-sleep-lock/63707349?noredirect=1#comment112656599_63707349) a far superior approach.

Comment: Ths isn't for you because it's invasive, if being invasive isn't a problem then there is no problems with the solution i gave. I never said my solution was perfect or something similler. you also should take the tour again, that would help you understand that your first commentary isn't very pertinent too. And i'm agree that the way to do this you recommended after that is better.